# TypeError: sphereArea() missing 1 required positional argument: 'radius' using python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a code that will return to me the surface area of a sphere but i keep getting the error sphereArea() missing 1 required positional argument :'radius'

```
 import math
 def sphereArea(radius):
     radius= int(input("The number you want as radius:"))
     surface_area= 4*math.pi*radius**2
     print("The surface area of the sphere is = ", surface_area)
 sphereArea()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're simply not passing an argument to your function call 'sphereArea' to fit parameter radius. Also, you are re-assigning that value in the first lint of your functions definition, that won't work. You are trying to do two things at once and too much for one function. Generally, you want your functions to return a value, then use that value.

```
 import math
 def sphereArea(radius):
     radius= int(input("The number you want as radius:")) # Here is bad
     surface_area= 4*math.pi*radius**2
     print("The surface area of the sphere is = ", surface_area)
 sphereArea() # Here as well
```

New code:

```
import math
 def sphereArea(radius):
     surface_area = 4*math.pi*radius**2
     return surface_area

inp_radius = int(input("The number you want as radius:"))
surface_area = sphereArea(inp_radius)
print("The surface area of the sphere is = ", surface_area)
```

Comment: sorry for being a bother but after using your code and typing sphereArea() at the end it still gives me the same error.. i'm i not supposed to use it or?

Comment: To reiterate: your definition of the function sphereArea contains in it a a parameter, 'radius'. This means, when the function is called, it requires an argument passed to it to take the place of radius. So, when you call sphereArea, you need to pass an number in between the paranthesis. i.e. sphereArea(10), or sphereArea(some_variable). Other functions have multiple paramters, like add(6, 10) or add(10, some_number). etc. Anyways, in the code I wrote up, your function is already being called and passed a variable, which is the user's input as you have elicited.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking the user to input the radius inside the function `sphereArea`, you do not need to have it as an argument:

```
 import math

 def sphereArea():
     radius = int(input("The number you want as radius:"))
     surface_area = 4 * math.pi * radius**2
     print("The surface area of the sphere is = ", surface_area)

 sphereArea()
```

Comment: this is how the question actually goes;

Comment: write definitions for this function; sphereArea(radius) returns the area of a sphere having the given radius

Answer (score 0):

when you define a function, the part in brackets, is where you list any arguments that you want passed into your function. You can think of arguments like inputs. If you define a function with inputs, but then don't give the function any inputs, python will give you an error. There are two ways you could potentially fix this code.

Method 1 (Here your function doesn't require any inputs/arguments):

```
 import math
 def sphereArea():     #Just get rid of the argument in your function definition
     radius= int(input("The number you want as radius:"))
     surface_area= 4*math.pi*radius**2
     print("The surface area of the sphere is = ", surface_area)
 sphereArea()
```

Method 2 (we move the input line since it becomes redundant inside the function. The idea is your pass the value as an input into the function):

```
 import math
 def sphereArea(radius):
     radius= int(input("The number you want as radius:"))
     surface_area= 4*math.pi*radius**2
     print("The surface area of the sphere is = ", surface_area)

 required_radius= int(input("The number you want as radius:")) 
 sphereArea(required_radius) #You have now passed your value into the function to be used.
```